# Good code commenting tips

Tags: java, javascript, php, c++

When I started to code my application I was not very carefully about commenting my code. Later I regret of course. This have happened a lot of times, and Im looking for some tips about how to do a effective commenting of code where I still understand what I have wrote. I don't want to end up like this

```
 //When I wrote this code only my and god understood what it did... now only god do
```

Comment: Comment on *what* the code does, not *how* it does it. Add a brief comment for every class, public class member and free function with external linkage, i.e. anything that someone else might use at some point.

Comment: It's also crucial to comment *why* something is done.

Comment: The book, Clean Code, has a good chapter on commenting and how to effectively use them.

One important thing to keep in mind for much better comment use is to always choose good names for identifiers and methods/functions so that you won't need as many comments because the names will be descriptive enough to guide you through your code. Readability is very important to good, clean code.

Comment: If you wrote code that you didn't understand later then ask yourself -- not us, yourself -- two questions: (1) could I have written this code so that I would understand it without comments? and (2) if no, then what comments would have let me understand this code?  The only person who can answer your question is you.

Comment: It’s so unreasonable that this question is closed. It could be argued that this is not opinion based. Some mods just wanted extra rep. Closing questions like this objectively makes stackoverflow worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.ca/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882) describes a good way (in my opinion) on how to deal with comments.

the tl;dr of that section is:

- Prefer to refactor methods / variables / classes so they describe what they're doing better
- Less is more, if there's too many comments, people are less likely to read them
- Comments can become out of date, the code does not
- As a last-resort, write a comment to describe the intent of the code

In your particular example about the comment about not knowing what you were doing, you should refactor that code.  If you cannot even describe what code you wrote does, then that's definitely bad code.  A *good* comment does not make up for writing bad code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Explain algorithms whenever they are unclear from the code semantics (**have** humanly readable variable and method names preferably over commenting them!!).
2. Document metrics as far these aren't clear from your variable/parameter/function names (e.g. `int distance_in_meters;`, `int dist_cm;`, `int calc_dist_cm(point a, point b);`)
3. Explain interfaces and their behavior (on class level).
4. Explain hacks you have to implement, to deal with clumsy 3rd party or OS interfaces.

Everything else in your code should be expressed by using proper naming of classes, (member) variables/functions and usage of standard algorithms.

Example:

```
// represents a point (x,y value) in a cartesian coordinate system
class point {
public:
    point(double x, double y);
    // Copy constructor for point
    point(const point& rhs);
    double x() const; // get x value
    void x(double value): // set x value
    double y() const; // get y value
    void y(double value): // set y value

    // Calculates the distance from an 'other' point in cartesian units
    double getDistance(const point& other) const;      
private:
    double x_;
    double y_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Document **why** you decided to employ certain designs. Usually, in software engineering and programming, there are dozens of solutions to achieve a certain task, and it's important to know the weighing of pros and cons which eventually resulted in your decision to use solution X.

This is especially important if your design deviates from an established standard idiom in your programming language or when you seemingly reimplement the wheel but have good reasons for doing so (legacy systems, extreme conditions on a certain client's system, time pressure due to some deadline, compatibility with some library or framework, and the like).

Answer (score 0):

Different commenting style suit for different scenarios and projects. Languages change over time, so is commenting style.

First thing to keep in mind is that comment is only one thing among many to keep code understandable by human. In big companies and large projects, documents such as specs, test plans are the duct tape gluing everything together. And in many modern scripting languages, the coding style (naming conventions, interfacing choices etc) are no less important than your comment on what a snippet does. Adopting a good coding style in some languages can almost make the code self explanatory.

Second suggestion I have is to comment before you start coding. This is like sketching before you start drawing, it helps you clarify your own intention. If you can describe what you want to do and how you are going to do it in words, then you can surely do it in code.

At last, do not over comment, make each word meaningful will be nice to both of you and fellow maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

I write very little comments in my own code. I rely on:

1. Good names of functions
2. Consistent and good names of variables.
3. Using enums and other symbolic names for "constants".
4. Using type declarations that explain what the type is for.

Note that "good names" are contextual. A long complicated name that is repeated many times in a short piece of code isn't necessarily better than a short name. The key is that the name should be a good clue to what the variable does. Calling a variable `outerLoopVariable` isn't much better than calling it `i`. Calling a parameter used for the same purpose, the same name on a different but closely related function is definitely a good idea. That way, you know that it's the same thing in the next function.

Similarly, trying to figure out why a number is `1` or `17` in a piece of code isn't particularly easy at times, where if it's called `NumberOfElements` or `ColorGreen` makes much more sense.

If the parameters to a function aren't obvious from their type and name, then it probably needs a little comment before the function to explain what the inputs are, and what they should be.

Types are also important to:
 1. Ensure that you pass the right sort of thing to a function. 
 2. Give another hint as to "what this thing does".

For example. `char *buffer;` isn't as clear as `typedef char* PixelBuffer; PixelBuffer *buffer;`, despite pointing to exactly the same type, the latter version explains that the `buffer` is in fact not a text string, file buffer or something, but a buffer containing pixels.

Another often found "flaw" is the lack of following the rule of "a function should do one thing" - if you have a function that does many things, it can be really hard to determine if the function can be reused or not.

It is typically a good idea to stick to small functions, and have many of them. Modern compilers will do good inlining if it deems it beneficial (and it's likely that you get more efficient code either way if you don't repeat stuff all over the place).

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good thing to rely on comments because it will rot over time.  A better way to comment your code effectively is to:

- Choose good names (Variables, method, class)
- Use assert whenever is possible specially as pre and post conditions
- Use Unit Test.  Unit tests explain the method's behavior.
- KISS Keep it simple stupid and DRY Don't repeat yourself

Some people like to write some TODOs or FIXes in the code.  Instead, I would suggest you to use a Unit Test that fails.  Remember, you seldom need to write comments in your code and you should try to avoid it.

I suggest you to read Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship for further information.